# How to create signature using SHA256WithRSA and PKCS#8 in PHP

Tags: php, openssl, sha256

I wants to write the functionality to create a signature using the algorithem of `SHA256withRSA`, I have tried but nothing is printing.Can anyone please update my code.
I have tried but I am not able to identify my mistake.
Thnaks in advance!!

> My PHP code

```
<?php

$data = "Sample Text";

$private_key = <<<EOD
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIBOgIBAAJBANDiE2+Xi/WnO+s120NiiJhNyIButVu6zxqlVzz0wy2j4kQVUC4Z
RZD80IY+4wIiX2YxKBZKGnd2TtPkcJ/ljkUCAwEAAQJAL151ZeMKHEU2c1qdRKS9
sTxCcc2pVwoAGVzRccNX16tfmCf8FjxuM3WmLdsPxYoHrwb1LFNxiNk1MXrxjH3R
6QIhAPB7edmcjH4bhMaJBztcbNE1VRCEi/bisAwiPPMq9/2nAiEA3lyc5+f6DEIJ
h1y6BWkdVULDSM+jpi1XiV/DevxuijMCIQCAEPGqHsF+4v7Jj+3HAgh9PU6otj2n
Y79nJtCYmvhoHwIgNDePaS4inApN7omp7WdXyhPZhBmulnGDYvEoGJN66d0CIHra
I2SvDkQ5CmrzkW5qPaE2oO7BSqAhRZxiYpZFb5CI
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
EOD;

$binary_signature = "";

$algo = "SHA256WithRSA";
openssl_sign($data, $binary_signature, $private_key, $algo);
$signature = base64_encode($binary_signature);
echo $timestamp = time();// I need here PHP curent date and timestamp
echo "<br>";
print_r($signature);

?>
```

> UPDATED PHP CODE

```
<?php
$data = "Sample Text";

$private_key = <<<EOD
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIBOgIBAAJBANDiE2+Xi/WnO+s120NiiJhNyIButVu6zxqlVzz0wy2j4kQVUC4Z
RZD80IY+4wIiX2YxKBZKGnd2TtPkcJ/ljkUCAwEAAQJAL151ZeMKHEU2c1qdRKS9
sTxCcc2pVwoAGVzRccNX16tfmCf8FjxuM3WmLdsPxYoHrwb1LFNxiNk1MXrxjH3R
6QIhAPB7edmcjH4bhMaJBztcbNE1VRCEi/bisAwiPPMq9/2nAiEA3lyc5+f6DEIJ
h1y6BWkdVULDSM+jpi1XiV/DevxuijMCIQCAEPGqHsF+4v7Jj+3HAgh9PU6otj2n
Y79nJtCYmvhoHwIgNDePaS4inApN7omp7WdXyhPZhBmulnGDYvEoGJN66d0CIHra
I2SvDkQ5CmrzkW5qPaE2oO7BSqAhRZxiYpZFb5CI
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
EOD;

$binary_signature = "";

$algo = OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA256;
openssl_sign($data, $binary_signature, $private_key, $algo);
$signature = base64_encode($binary_signature);

//verify signature
$r = openssl_verify($data, $signature, $public_key_pem, "sha256WithRSAEncryption");
var_dump($r);
?>
```

Comment: Turn your error reporting on/up and you'll see "PHP Warning:  openssl_sign(): Unknown signature algorithm." Use the constant `OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA256` and you'll get the signature `"xEjyq+pwgRLpc+ikNT8HQRiE+vYtHjwaBafhaqW1ueu8ftxvg1PDtPZ1jQGjwvtuixk+yg90nbpjF0nUBshqNA=="`

Comment: I am using `OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA256` getting error ( ! ) Warning: openssl_sign(): Unknown signature algorithm. in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\index.php on line 20

Comment: Note that you use it as a _constant_, not a string.

Comment: Can you please post your answer here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can view a good example on [PHP.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-sign.php). In the below example, it generates and saves private_key.pem, public_key.pem and signature.dat.

There are built-in algorithm constants. You can view them [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/openssl.signature-algos.php). You have to use these as **Constant**. Example: `openssl_sign(data, $signature, $pkeyid, OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA256)`

Also, you can check any other algorithm by running **openssl_get_md_methods()**. You can see more detail [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-get-md-methods.php). Notice that these algorithms are not constant. You have to define these ones as a string. Example: `openssl_sign(data, $signature, $pkeyid, 'sha256')`

```
<?php
//data you want to sign
$data = 'my data';

//create new private and public key
$new_key_pair = openssl_pkey_new(array(
    "private_key_bits" => 2048,
    "private_key_type" => OPENSSL_KEYTYPE_RSA,
));
openssl_pkey_export($new_key_pair, $private_key_pem);

$details = openssl_pkey_get_details($new_key_pair);
$public_key_pem = $details['key'];

//create signature
openssl_sign($data, $signature, $private_key_pem, OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA256);

//save for later
file_put_contents('private_key.pem', $private_key_pem);
file_put_contents('public_key.pem', $public_key_pem);
file_put_contents('signature.dat', $signature);

//verify signature
$r = openssl_verify($data, $signature, $public_key_pem, "sha256WithRSAEncryption");
var_dump($r);
?>
```

**EDIT**

In your situation, please try the below code:

```
$data = "Sample Text";

$private_key = <<<EOD
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIBOgIBAAJBANDiE2+Xi/WnO+s120NiiJhNyIButVu6zxqlVzz0wy2j4kQVUC4Z
RZD80IY+4wIiX2YxKBZKGnd2TtPkcJ/ljkUCAwEAAQJAL151ZeMKHEU2c1qdRKS9
sTxCcc2pVwoAGVzRccNX16tfmCf8FjxuM3WmLdsPxYoHrwb1LFNxiNk1MXrxjH3R
6QIhAPB7edmcjH4bhMaJBztcbNE1VRCEi/bisAwiPPMq9/2nAiEA3lyc5+f6DEIJ
h1y6BWkdVULDSM+jpi1XiV/DevxuijMCIQCAEPGqHsF+4v7Jj+3HAgh9PU6otj2n
Y79nJtCYmvhoHwIgNDePaS4inApN7omp7WdXyhPZhBmulnGDYvEoGJN66d0CIHra
I2SvDkQ5CmrzkW5qPaE2oO7BSqAhRZxiYpZFb5CI
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
EOD;

$binary_signature = "";

$algo = OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA256;
openssl_sign($data, $binary_signature, $private_key, $algo);
$signature = base64_encode($binary_signature);
echo $timestamp = time();// I need here PHP curent date and timestamp
echo "<br>";
print_r($signature);
```

Comment: I tried your code, throwing warning message, signature not getting created

Comment: What is the warning message? Again "Warning: openssl_sign(): Unknown signature algorithm"?

Comment: `OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA256` is equivalent to `SHA256withRSA` this? because i wants to implement in `SHA256withRSA`

Comment: your `Edit` answer working fine. `OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA256` is equivalent to `SHA256withRSA` this?

Comment: yes, you can verify it with this: `openssl_verify($data, $signature, $public_key_pem, "sha256WithRSAEncryption");`

Comment: Can you pleasse check my `UPDATED PHP CODE` section i am getting error ( ! ) Warning: openssl_verify(): supplied key param cannot be coerced into a public key in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\index.php on line 25

Comment: C:\xampp\htdocs\test\index.php:26:boolean false

Comment: openssl_verify() was an example.. You need public_key for this. You have to rewrite your code based on my reply.

Comment: openssl_verify() funtion instead of `$public_key_pem` variable i wants to pass my `public key value`, is it correct?

Comment: Yes and pass the `$binary_signature`.

Comment: Thanks!! I am realy happy.